# Common class for CharBuffer and StringWriter?

Tags: java

Assume I want to write a long string where I do not know its length in advance, but I can subsequently provide substrings that would just need to be concatenated in the end.

It seems like I can use the classes [CharBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) and [StringWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) for that purpose. StringWriter seems to grow over time as needed such that I can construct strings of almost arbitrary length this way, whereas CharBuffer seems only to be applicable for situations where I know an upper bound for my string length in advance. Is that correct?

However, I am looking for a general class that would do this task, where I could tell whether its length should be fixed (as with CharBuffer) or flexible (as with StringWriter) at creation time. (The option for fixed length is intended for situations where buffer-full-errors are preferred over problems that arise from too much memory consumption.) Is there such a class?

If not and if I need to implement it myself, what would be a good name for it? Considering the classes mentioned above, "buffer" seems to be limited to fixed length structures, whereas "writer" seems to be limited to growing structured. Thank you!

Comment: If you use `StringBuilder` instead, both it and `CharBuffer` implement `Appendable` and `CharSequence`.

Comment: How can I limit the maximum capacity of StringBuilder? What is the difference in capacity growing behaviour compared to StringWriter?

Comment: I think you need to create your own class that contains three members: `StringBuilder` for storing the string, `int` for storing the capacity and `boolean` to indicate whether to grow StringBuilder beyond the capacity or not. Maybe name the class `VariableLengthBuffer`.

Comment: @Abra, thank you, but it looks like the Term "variable-length buffer" is already used for something else: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_buffer

Comment: The term [rectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle) is already used for something else. Doesn't stop it from being used as a Java [class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.desktop/java/awt/Rectangle.html) name. But hey, it was just a suggestion, based solely on my interpretation of your question. I assume that you are developing software for telecommunication, hence your reluctance to use the name `VariableLengthBuffer`. What about `MaybeLimitedLengthBuffer`?

Comment: You already have a way to tell whether the length is fixed:  `boolean fixed = (appendable instanceof Buffer);`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you could consider [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: How can I limit the maximum capacity of StringBuilder? What is the difference in capacity growing behaviour compared to StringWriter?

Comment: If I understood the question, in some circumstances the OP wants the buffer **not** to grow beyond its initial capacity. Even though you can indicate a capacity when you construct a `StringBuilder` it will still grow once that capacity is reached and hence I'm not sure whether it is appropriate.